# ¿Cómo poner borde a una imagen con código php?

Tags: php

Investigando he podido hacer el siguiente código:

```
$im = imagecreate(400, 300);
$color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$borderThickness = 10;

$resource = fopen($images['tmp_name'][$i], 'r + b');

drawBorder($resource, $color, $borderThickness, $images['tmp_name'][$i]);

move_uploaded_file($images['tmp_name'][$i], $target)
```

Donde `$target` es la ruta donde subiré la imagen. Y la función es:

```
function drawBorder($img, $color, $thickness, $filename)
{
    $x1 = 10;
    $y1 = 10;
    //$x2 = imagesx($img) - 1;
    //$y2 = imagesy($img) - 1;
    //$dim= list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
    //print_r( $dim[0]);

    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

    if ($image) {
        $height = imagesy($image) -1;
        $width = imagesx($image) - 1;
        //imagedestroy($image);
    }

    for($i = 0; $i < $thickness; $i++)
    {
        imagerectangle($image, $x1++, $y1++, $width++, $height++, $color);
    }

}
```

Pero al momento de guardarla no muestra ningún borde. Quiero ponerle un borde  de color negro a cualquier imagen que suba pero necesito hacerlo con `php` como pueden ver.

Comment: Entiendo que quieres devolver una imagen con el borde "incrustado", no te sirve que lo haga el cliente con CSS o HTML...¿si?

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que guardar la imagen modificada en una ubicación de tu elección:

```
imagejpeg($image, "ruta/a/tu/imagen.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no escribiste `$resource` al sistema, sólo modificaste en memoria y terminaste la ejecución.

Te faltaría abrir en modo escritura `wb` y luego escribir al disco.

Answer (score 0):

Para que te sirva para todos tus proyectos te puedo decir que en html usamos en el css el border radius para redondear las esquinas.
En php podrías hacer algo así:

```
.miclasse { border-radius: 10px; }
```

Pon un div o una imagen que se asocie a tu class.
Creo que tanto en php como en html funciona igual aunque se escribe diferente. Para mi es la mejor manera de redondear esquinas.